# Unable to connect to a site from Testcafe IDE on OSX

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

My fixtures are set up like so

```
{
  "fixtures": [
    {
      "name": "login",
      "pageUrl": "http:\/\/localhost:3000\/",
      "tests": [
        {
          "name": "type name",
          "commands": [
            {
              "type": "type-text",
              "studio": {

              },
              "callsite": "0",
              "selector": {
                "type": "js-expr",
                "value": "input[type=email]"
              },
              "options": {

              },
              "text": "example@email.com"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

with one simple test to find the input and type some text but when running the command I get

```
testcafe chrome login.testcafe
ERROR Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser connections. This can be caused by network issues or remote device failure.

Type "testcafe -h" for help.
```

I've seen this issue a couple of times on their issues board one relating to CI integration on a Linux server and another which seems like a similar issue of trying to connect to localhost

> https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-browser-provider-electron/issues/20
>   https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1133

New to testcafe any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution some network policies don't allow access to your machine on some ports in my example it's 57501.

```
testcafe chrome login.testcafe --hostname localhost
```

adding --hostname resolves the issue

documentation

> https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#--hostname-name

I still don't know how to launch from the IDE but this resolves my main issue.

Answer (score 2):

TestCafe Studio Preview does not support setting command line options (hostname in your case). The TestCafe team is going to implement this functionality in the official release.

So, for now, it is only possible to run tests via a command line.

UPDATE:

You can set the hostname option in the [TestCafe Studio Settings dialog](https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/400356/user-interface/preferences-settings-dialog):

[image]

Comment: How would you get around using the record feature without having these settings available? I guess it's not possible. Thanks for your answer cleared up alot